# Copy data from Azure Service Bus Topic to a Storage Account inside Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to move data received in my Service Bus Topic to a Storage Account inside Azure.
I believe Azure Function is one of the good ways to achieve this.
Please share suitable example if you have one.

Regards,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

Fire up an Azure Functions project, create a function with a [Service Bus trigger binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---example) (if you're in the portal or Visual Studio then it'll offer you a template) and add a storage output binding for [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---example), [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output---example) or [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output---example) as appropriate. Then in the function code just copy the relevant data from your trigger parameter to your output parameter.