# Read records from large xlsx/csv files and post it to azure service bus topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-data-factory

We receive large feed files(excel/csv) of ~5gb size every night, need to read and have to post one record after another from the file to azure service bus topic. Is it possible using Azure Data Factory, if yes, how? or any other better azure based solution available? please suggest.

Comment: How do you receive the file?

Comment: Some other upstream system drops excel/csv file everynight to azure storage

Comment: @191180rk , did you find a flexible solution for your case?

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory doesn't support Azure Service Bus topic. So it's impossible to using Azure Data Factory
[image]

For more details, please see : [Supported data stores and formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats).

I think [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) may can help you achieve it.
You can reference :

1. [Azure Blob storage bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).
   This article explains how to work with Azure Blob storage bindings in Azure Functions. Azure Functions supports trigger, input, and output bindings for blobs. The article includes a section for each binding: Blob trigger, Blob input binding,Blob output binding.
2. [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus). This article explains how to work with Azure Service Bus bindings in Azure Functions. Azure Functions supports trigger and output bindings for Service Bus queues and topics

Here is a blog about [Copy data from Azure Service Bus Topic to a Storage Account inside Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608947/copy-data-from-azure-service-bus-topic-to-a-storage-account-inside-azure).

We don't know how much time it will take. Azure Functions has two kinds of pricing plans:Consumption plan and App Service plan.

Azure Functions in a Consumption plan are limited to 10 minutes for a single execution. In the Premium plan, the run duration defaults to 30 minutes to prevent runaway executions. However, you can modify the host.json configuration to make this unbounded for Premium plan apps.

For more details, please reference: [Azure Functions Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan).

Maybe Azure Function is not fit for this long process, but can help you execute this long process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I want to loop through all million records in excel sheet once it is made available & I have to post record after record to Azure Service Bus Topic one after another. Going by your suggestion, will Azure function fit it for this long process?

Comment: Please see my update. Hope my answer can helps you.

Comment: Azure function doesn't seem like efficient way of doing it. If I convert excel to csv file, will I expect azure data factory to iterating over every single row in csv file(dataset) in a single activity and post every single row to azure service bus?please suggest some robust,efficient solution.

Comment: Hi @thiru, I'm sorry for that I don't have some better suggestions for you. Because Azure Data Factory doesn't support Azure Service Bus topic. If my answer helps, could you please accept or vote it? Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Sorry  Leon Yue, your above answer not helping me. Can anyone suggest any relevant azure based solution to iterate over every single row in excel/csv file and post every single row to azure service bus topic?

Comment: That's all right. I also hope others can give you more suggestions.